# Why should I use methodinvoker instead of declaring a void method and calling it?

Tags: c#

I'm using asynchronus socket operations and when the client receives a message it calls a method with the code below and executes the Methodinvoker:

```
private void AddText(string message)
        {
            MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                textBox1.Text += message;
            });
            this.Invoke(mi);
        }
```

I don't understand why is methodinvoker used.
It is better to use it instead of declaring and calling a void method without parameters? there must be a good reason.

Comment: Declaring a "void method" will do no good, you need a delegate type.  Nothing wrong with the ones already available in the .NET framework.  Including Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your method is being called from another thread then your main thread.

[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx):

> > Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

You should always interact with your user control on the main thread. The `Invoke` method posts the delegate back to the main thread of the application.